# Join em três tabelas não mostra todos os resultados

Tags: mysql, query, select, join

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
produto_unidades
join produto_notas on produto_notas.id = produto_unidades.produtoNota_id
join produto_licitacoes on produto_licitacoes.id = produto_notas.produtoLicitacoes_id
where produto_unidades.unidade_id = 2
```

O join funciona corretamente, mas preciso que TODOS os produtos da tabela `produto_licitacoes` sejam exibidos, independente de não ter relacionamento nas outras tabelas.

Comment: Tentou o `right join`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tentei, sem resultado

Comment: Consegue fazer um [mcve] demonstrando as estruturas das tabelas e registros de exemplos? Pode usar o http://sqlfiddle.com para mostrar como está.

Comment: acredito que não conseguiu pois o segundo join pode ter travado alguns resultados..

Comment: @rLinhares pode explicar melhor?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo acho que viajei =p maso comentário sobre o right join ajudou a resolver? minha resposta serviu de algo??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o [`left join`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) (deixei a tabela "principal" primeiro para ficar evidenciada como tal, mas podes manter a estrutura que já está e usar o [`right join`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp))

```
SELECT 
*
FROM produto_licitacoes 
left join produto_unidades on produto_licitacoes.id = produto_notas.produtoLicitacoes_id
left join produto_notas on produto_notas.id = produto_unidades.produtoNota_id
where produto_unidades.unidade_id = 2
```